# Mount directory in docker by specifying path as argument

Tags: python, docker

I have a python script that take two path, one as input folder and other as output folder via sys.argv. For example

`python script.py from to`

If no path is provided let say `python script.py`. It take default folder which is `from` and `to`.

I have created a docker image and i am mounting my local folder this way

`docker run -v "$(pwd):/folder" myimage`

As in this case I am not providing folder name argument, it take them by default and put them in `folder` folder of docker. This is working

But if i want to pass custom path,let how can i do that?

EDIT:
Let say here is the code

```
argl = len(sys.argv)
if argl==1:
    dir_from = 'from'
    dir_to   = 'to'
elif argl == 3:
    dir_from  = sys.argv[1]
    dir_to    = sys.argv[2]
```

So if i pass
`python script.py`  the first if condition will work, and if i pass argument like `python script.py abc/from abc/to` the second elif condition work.

`docker run -v "$(pwd):/folder" myimage` This command pick the first condition, but how to pass custom path to it.

For example some thing link that
`docker run -v "abc/from abc/to:/folder" myimage`

Comment: Aren't you already doing that?  Isn't your use of `${pwd}` above kinda what you're talking about?  You can define parameters that are used to define mounts in your docker run command, and so you don't have to hard code the paths on either the host or container sides.

Comment: so how i define both output and input, here i am define only one folder. which is a directory already have two folder `from` and `to`, let say if i change the spellings, it did not know which folder to pick. the above command is using default `from` and `to` folder

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  So you're saying that within the directory you're mounting as a volume, you have some subdirs that you'll want your code running in the container to access, but you don't want to have to hard code the names of those subdirs in that code?  Does that summarize your issue?

Comment: I guess maybe it's not quite that.  I guess maybe you're asking about running `python script.py` where you could supply two paths, but you'd like to not have to.  You then want to be able to have the code use default path values, but you don't want to  hard-code the default paths that are used by your program.  Is that the issue?

Comment: In either case, I think the answer to your question is going to be to use environment variables to pass information into your container.  You could define and pass in two env vars, FROM_PATH and TO_PATH.  When you launch your container, you get the current values you want to use for the defaults by whatever logic you choose, and you set these env vars to those values.  Then in the code in the container, you use the values of those env vars.  If the "from" argv parameter isn't supplied, then you use the value of the env var FROM_PATH.  Does this help?

Comment: I have updated the question, can you please check

Comment: So yes, I think what you have is exactly what I was considering in my second to last comment above.  You pass in two env vars FROM_PATH and TO_PATH.  Then, in your Python code in your container, instead of using the hard coded string `'from'` as the default value, you use `os.getenv('FROM_PATH')`.  Same for the other param/path. So you can still override the paths by passing them in as arguments to your script.  But now you can also configure what the defaults are at runtime rather than having to hard-code them into the container.

Comment: thanks alot. i was thinking i have to pass the path in command , let me see how to do in environment variable

Comment: I'm guessing that you're new to Docker.  I didn't used to like using environment variables to pass data to a program.  But that's the way everyone does it with Docker.  I just had to get over my bias.  Now my company and I have dozens of container definitions.  Quite possibly every one of them makes use of at least one env var in this way.  It's just the way to do it.

Comment: Env vars aren't the only possibility.  All that really matters is that when your code first runs, and it sees that it didn't get passed the to and from params, it then has to get the defaults from somewhere.  Could be hard coded strings.  Could be a HTTP API call that it makes.  Could be a database query.  Where those defaults come from are up to you.  The determining factor is where those values ultimately come from.  Grabbing them from their source locations and passing them into the container via env vars is a very common practice.  We do it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to pass in default values for your `from` and `to` path parameters at the time that you launch your container.

Define the two env vars as part of launching your container:

```
FROM_PATH = <get the from path default from wherever is appropriate>
TO_PATH = <get the from path default from wherever is appropriate>
```

Launch your container:

```
docker run -e FROM_PATH -e TO_PATH ... python script.py
```

You could specify the values for the env vars in the run command itself via something like `-e FROM_PATH=/a/b/c`.  If you don't provide values, the values are assumed to be already defined in local env vars with the same name, as I did above.

Then inside your container code:

```
argl = len(sys.argv)
if argl==1:
    dir_from = os.getenv('FROM_PATH')
    dir_to   = os.getenv('TO_PATH')
elif argl == 3:
    dir_from  = sys.argv[1]
    dir_to    = sys.argv[2]
```